# Read multiple parquet files with different schema in scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark-sql, parquet

I have multiple parquet files in different directories and would like to read them in sequence by parameterization in Scala.

The problem is the schema information is not standard and column names vary drastically.

For example: what might be called `load_date` in 1 directory can be called `load_dt` in  a parquet file from another directory.

So i'm being forced to use different read.parquet().select statements for each directory. (there are more than 30)

Is there a way by which i can use the same statement and switch schema information based on a parameter of some sort? Maybe like a client name or ID?